# MySQl, why would completly the wrong index be used?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I've been optimizing a query on my test server, which has the same indexes as the live server. And when I explain the query on both servers I get a different index being used.

It not just a slight difference its an index which just doesn't fit at all.

This is my query

```
SELECT count(Pads.PadID) AS CountOfPadID FROM Pads WHERE ((
RemoveMeDate='2001-01-01 00:00:00') AND (catid between 0 and 11)) 
ORDER BY VersionAddDate DESC;
```

Test server explain
[image]

Live server explain
[image]

Heres the indexes on the live server, you can see index Cats doesn't relate to the fields used in the query at all
[image]

I've tried `USE INDEX (sitempacats)` which does work, but I'm just puzzled why it would do this ?

Comment: are the mysql versions different?

Comment: Have you tried mysql dumping the table from the live server and importing it on the test server? And are the test server and live server exactly the same? mysql version / compiled addons

Comment: Do you have same version of mysql on both servers? Probably query optimizer works differently in different versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes used in query execution not only depends on the indexes you have but also the data in the database. And other several statistics  used to generate execution plan.

Comment: Yep. Just compare the number of rows involved on the two servers. No surprise really that a plan to deal with 2 rows might be different than one to deal with 11,530 rows.